# Can we create report on custom setting in Salesforce?

Tags: reporting, customsetting

Can we create report on custom setting in Salesforce?

when i edit the object that is created for custom settings, it directs to the custom setting edit page, so i cannot edit and check 'enable report' option

Answer (score 2):

No, we cannot create a **report** on a custom setting in Salesforce. Custom settings are not reportable objects, and they do not appear in the report builder or the report type editor. Custom settings are designed to store data that is accessed by **formulas**, **validation rules**, **Apex**, or the **API**. They are not meant to store data that is displayed or analyzed in reports.

If you want to create a report on custom setting data, you have some possible alternatives, such as:

- Creating a custom object that mirrors the custom setting data, and using a trigger or a batch job to sync the data between the custom object and the custom setting. You can then create a report on the custom object using the standard report builder or a custom report type.
- Creating a Visualforce page or a Lightning component that queries the custom setting data using Apex or SOQL, and displays the data in a table or a chart. You can then embed the Visualforce page or the Lightning component in a dashboard or a record page to create a report on the custom setting data.

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdeVqUAJ/let-reports-access-custom-settings

Comment: The linked idea is a good one, but doesn't really relate to reporting ON custom settings and is about reports USING custom settings.

Answer (score 1):

Custom settings were never meant to be used for this purpose, so you cannot report on them. You can query and search for them in the API and Apex, though.